# dplyr mutate, applying functions that incorporate variables (or objects, vectors) outside the data frame of interest

Tags: r, dplyr

### Problem

I am curious how I might apply a function to the `mutate` function from `dplyr`, which requires an argument that is a vector I define elsewhere.

I have an example that is somewhat abstracted from what I am actually trying to do (I am taking several columns, checking for the presence of values in those columns for that row that depend on the Date of the table, and then return a string classification), however for the sake of brevity the following example produces the same error, and hopefully will suffice.

### Setup

```
DF <- data.frame(
  Index = 1:100, 
  Num1 = runif(100,0,100) %/% 1
  )

# array to check
CheckArray = seq(0,100, by = 2)

f <- function(x, ArrayToCheck){
  if (x %in% ArrayToCheck){
    return(T)
  } else {
    return(F)
  }
}
```

### My attempt

```
DF <- dplyr::mutate(
  DF,
  Num1_even = f(Num1, CheckArray)
  )
```

which of course returns an error

> Warning message:
>       In if (x %in% ArrayToCheck) { :
>         the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

### Extra note

I should point out that I am aware my example could be solved other ways without a function, e.g.

```
dplyr::mutate(
  DF,
  Num1_even = Num1 %in% CheckArray
)
```

or

```
dplyr::mutate(
     DF,
     Num1_even = Num1 %in% seq(0,100, by = 2)
)
```

But in this case and many others, I often find it valuable to define a vector outside of my DF, and then apply a function with to each row along with multiple additional arguments.

I have also seen this solved via the apply family of functions, but I was hoping there was a method in `dplyr`, since it's so fast and has such nice syntax.

---

Perhaps we can get the Hadleyverse to add an operator that tells `dplyr` to step outside the scope of the current data.frame, e.g.

```
CheckArray = seq(0,100, by = 2)

DF <- dplyr::mutate(
  DF,
  Num1_even = f(Num1, %o%CheckArray%o%)
  )
```

---

Comment: This reflects how your function is constructed. It doesn't take vector input,  so you need `rowwise` to make it work. `DF %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Num1_even = f(Num1, CheckArray))`

Comment: I have the same issue with the code you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `CheckArray` vector. The problem is that `if` statements are not vectorized in `R`. You can use `ifelse` instead. Then your call should work. Check out `?ifelse` for more information.

```
f <- function(x, ArrayToCheck){
  ifelse(x %in% ArrayToCheck, TRUE, FALSE)
}

dplyr::mutate(
  DF,
  Num1_even = f(Num1, CheckArray)
)
```

Of course in this case the `ifelse` is not actually needed either (see below). If your desired output consists only of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, you can skip the `ifelse`, but I added `ifelse` in case your actual example is more complicated than that.

```
f <- function(x, ArrayToCheck){
  x %in% ArrayToCheck
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I think I suffer from the error of designing too many of my functions around scalar inputs. Do you, by chance, have advice on resources to ensure my functions are all able to handle vector arguments more properly in future?

Comment: The `?Vectorize` function comes to mind. But generally it's just a good idea to test your function with a vector argument quickly. If  `f(1:2, ArrayToCheck)` works, all should be fine.